# Story about spreading virus re-writing itself to be able to run on any processor and any machine

Tags: story-identification, virus

A few years ago I followed a link posed in a comment somewhere in the SE ecosystem. The link pointed to a SF story about a virus spreading to any machine, learning by trial-and-error which instructions would achieve the desired result.

The virus was discovered accidentally, when someone noticed a very inefficient machine code. Removal of that code was impossible, since it was present on the entire network.

Later the guy finds out that there are many people in the world aware of the problem, but they switched back to paper-based messages - to ensure safe communication.

And I cannot find the link or the story any more :( I would like to re-read it.

The story is relatively short, not more than 2 computer screens, as far as I remember.

Even though there might be a virus like that in reality, the story was written as being fictional.

---

I actually remember more of the story, but I do not want to spoil the fun of reading for others - in case that we find the correct answer.

---

Update: after the answer was published, I understood that I did not really remember enough :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like "Coding Machines" by Lawrence Kesteloot, which can be read here: https://www.teamten.com/lawrence/writings/coding-machines/

Comment: You beat me to it! Good job!

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to the site!  Thanks for posting an answer and helping out.  It will be more helpful, though, it you could edit in a few words, or an excerpt, which show why this is a good match.

Comment: I am filled with shame :( I can honestly say that indeed I did NOT remember MOST of the story (I mean, the debugging and compiler writing). Or I might have read some abridged version. Thank you for the story, and congrats on the promptness. :)